# Parsing webpage with Jsoup. why is the behaviour on Android different?

Tags: java, android, html, parsing, jsoup

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
```

If I run this code in Android I get a html code with 535 lines (length:42599).

If I run this code in a sample desktop application get a html code with 2050 lines (length:292782, that is CORRECT. Same JSoup library of course.

Can anyone explain me why?

Comment: I set UserAgent and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting desktop user agent

```
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0").timeout(TIMEOUT).get();
```

I get the right html code.

Thanks to Tom Reznik